# Can I run Windows 7 Ultimate in VirtualBox on a Windows Home Server host?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-media-center, windows-home-server

I'm considering migrating from my very noisy and large MythTV box to something much smaller and quieter, like the [HP MediaSmart Server LX195](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16859105503).  To accomplish this I would need to install a virtual machine that runs Windows 7 Home Premium or Windows 7 Ultimate on the Windows Home Server box.  Tuner drivers are not a problem for me because I already have an [HDHomeRun](http://www.silicondust.com/products/hdhomerun_home_atsc), and playback shouldn't be an issue because I have an XBox360 to play back all of my content.  Dedidcated drive space for the VM shouldn't be an issue because I have a [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/) with lots of space.  However, coming from a Linux and Mac background I've got some questions about this solution:

1. Can I install a virtual machine host software such as VirtualBox or VMWare Player on the Windows Home Server machine?
2. When watching content on the 360, will I still have access to the plugins.  For example, if I install [My Movies](http://www.mymovies.dk/) will that functionality be available on the XBox 360?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes you will, providing you don't want to run a 64bits VM on a 32bits host
2) Don't expect VMs to run anything graphics related on a VM

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for.  Eventually I just settled on two separate boxes. The automatic sleep feature of Windows 7 makes it quite nice and quiet. The original plan had me using a 360 as an extender, which worked, but the new solution seems to work better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. yes
2. you want to run Media Center in a virtual machine? i think not! :)

here's an article from someone who tried to feed an xbox 360 via [Vista Media Center with My Movies in MS VPC](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2007/03/15/vista-ultimate-media-center-in-virtual-pc-form---not.aspx):

> ...and this is where my fun ended.
>   Media Center instantly became entirely
>   unresponsive. Like, full seconds
>   between putting your mouse cursor over
>   a menu option and having the menu
>   option highlight in preparation to be
>   clicked. Removed the DVD from the
>   drive and things became mildly
>   responsive again.

Comment: I have also heard that Media Center does not do well in any VM.  I know I could never get it working well in either VMWare or MSVPC.  Media Center is a graphics, memory and processor hog.

Comment: I'm not planning on using the VM as the frontend for Media Center.  That's what the 360 is for.  I'm looking to reduce the number of computers I have.